# Excel VBA How to convert multiple controls and variables into a universal function

Tags: excel, vba, variables, controls, userform

I have a -userform- that has 100 different controls (Textbox and combobox) and i am trying to consolidate one large chunk of code down to something smaller and universal... by basing it on the active control and using that as my reference point for calling another sub where the declared variables will become plug and play.

So here is the base code that works... But i would need to replicate this 25 times and I feel like there is a better way, but i cannot seem to figure it out...

```
Option Explicit

Public Gal, Kg, L, Qt, Pt, Lbs, C, FlOz, Ea, Prts, Oz, Tbs, Tsp, Dl, G, Ml As Integer

Private Sub M1_AfterUpdate() 'this is where the math happens

'I have 25 variables, M1:M25 -  by 16 variables, Gal:Ml for each

Gal = 128: Kg = 35.274: L = 33.814: Qt = 32: Pt = 16: Lbs = 16: C = 8 'multiply
FlOz = 1: Ea = 1: Prts = 1: Oz = 1 'stay
Tbs = 2: Tsp = 6: Dl = 3.381: G = 28.353: Ml = 29.574 'divide

'this is the base code that does ecactly what I need... But i would have to replicate this whole thing 25 times...

    If ActiveControl.Text = "Gal" Then C1.Value = Round(((Q1 * Gal) * (Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Inventory").Range("C6:L1006"), _
                                                Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(I1, Sheets("Inventory").Range("C6:C1006"), 0), 10))), 2)

    If ActiveControl.Text = "Kg" Then C1.Value = Round(((Q1 * Kg) * (Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Inventory").Range("C6:L1006"), _
                                                Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(I1, Sheets("Inventory").Range("C6:C1006"), 0), 10))), 2)

    If ActiveControl.Text = "L" Then C1.Value = Round(((Q1 * L) * (Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Inventory").Range("C6:L1006"), _
                                                Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(I1, Sheets("Inventory").Range("C6:C1006"), 0), 10))), 2)

' it goes on through each of the variables but i post it all, you get the idea ; )

End Sub
```

I have tried this road...THIS WAS A FAIL!!! I couldn't figure how to read it as a control name, it read as string.

I tried putting contol / controls in the front and that didnt work...

```
Option Explicit

Public Gal, Kg, L, Qt, Pt, Lbs, C, FlOz, Ea, Prts, Oz, Tbs, Tsp, Dl, G, Ml As Integer

Private Sub M1_AfterUpdate() 'this is where the math happens
Dim ActCtrl As Control: Set ActCtrl = ActiveControl.Name
Dim VarA As Integer
Dim x, y, z As String

If ActCtrl = M1 Then VarA = 1 ' 25 if lines written to represent 25 rows of form controls
'M2 is VarA=2 and so on till 25

'this puts them together, but it returns string.
    x = "I" & VarA
    y = "Q" & VarA
    z = "C" & VarA

    'this is where it would end
    z.Value = Round(((y * Ml) * (Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Inventory").Range("C6:L1006"), _
                                Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(x, Sheets("Inventory").Range("C6:C1006"), 0), 10))), 2)
```

I would like to be able to change this...

```
    If ActiveControl.Text = "Gal" Then C1.Value = Round(((Q1 * Gal) * (Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Inventory").Range("C6:L1006"), _
                                                Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(I1, Sheets("Inventory").Range("C6:C1006"), 0), 10))), 2)
```

into a plug and play using variables... If possible...

Comment: Create a two-column lookup table on a sheet, with Unit & Conversion Factor, and use vlookup to directly convert the units to the scaling value.   That's just a starting point though, since it seems that will only take care of part of the duplication you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a two-column lookup table on a sheet, with Unit & Conversion Factor, and use vlookup to directly convert the units to the scaling value.

Then factor almost all of the code out of your `M1_AfterUpdate` into generic methods to which you can just pass `M1` etc.

Something along these lines:

```
Private Sub M1_AfterUpdate() 
    HandleCombo M1 
End Sub

Private Sub M2_AfterUpdate() 
    HandleCombo M2 
End Sub
'etc for other combos


'handle a combo box changing
Sub HandleCombo(cmbo)
    Dim f, c as object
    f = GetScalingFactor(cmbo.Text)
    Set c = me.Controls(Replace(cmbo.Name, "M", "C")) 'corresponding text control
    c.Value = 'long formula which uses f
End Sub

'convert unit to scaling factor
Function GetScalingFactor(unit)
    Dim m, rv
    m = Application.Vlookup(unit, _
                            thisworkbook.sheets("lookup").Range("A2:B26"), _
                            2, False)
    If not iserror(m) then
        rv = m
    else
        'no match on the unit name - what to do here?
        rv = -1 'or raise an error
    end if
    GetScalingFactor = rv
End function
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me there IS an entire workbook in which I can use... lol Sometimes I try to over complicate things... So I broke it down even further and just built a conversion tool in a xlveryhidden sheet where I just populate the 3 variables and then return the result to the correct userform control... Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone comes across something like this, here is the fix... Thank you again for reminding me that there is a simple way!

Step 1: Build the tool in a worksheet... See picture. I used a series of index/match for mine... But what ever you need...

[The worksheet tool...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF6mZ.png)

Step 2 : In a separate module there is this bit... This is the code talks straight to the tool.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Conv_Loop()
Dim CtrlName

CtrlName = RecipeCost.CtrlName

    Sheets("Control").Range("C24").Value = RecipeCost.Controls("I" & CtrlName).Value
    Sheets("Control").Range("C25").Value = RecipeCost.Controls("Q" & CtrlName).Value
    Sheets("Control").Range("C26").Value = RecipeCost.Controls("M" & CtrlName).Value

    RecipeCost.Controls("C" & CtrlName).Value = Sheets("Control").Range("C28").Value

End Sub
```

Step 3: In the userform with the variables that need to talk to conversion manager, declare a public variable first. Then in the control you want to activate the function on put the declare your variable value, then just call for it. If you don't want to see the tool or make it available for other then set sheet to xlVeryHidden.

```
Option Explicit

Public CtrlName

Private Sub M1_AfterUpdate(): CtrlName = 1: Call Conv_Loop: End Sub
```

That took a world of stupid that I was trying to do and made it very easy!!!

Shout out to Tim Williams for reminding me... "Create a two-column lookup table on a sheet", that's all it took...